# Android make overlaping FloatingActionButton on BottomNavigation

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I would like to design this layout on my project:

[image]

as many googleing AFIAK is some library to can design that on Android but I can't find it, I take this screen shot from Android material website. Can anybody help me to design that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[At the bottom of the material design page](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#implementation) there's a link on how you can implement that on Android, Flutter, iOS, etc.

As for Android, you'll have to use the `BottomAppBar` widget to achieve what you want. You can also read more about it [on the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Other components and views -->

  <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24"/>

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Taken from [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/).

You can change the FAB position by using the method [`setAnchorId(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams#setAnchorId(int)) with the following parameters:

- [`FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar.html#FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER)
- [`FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar.html#FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END)

Alternatively you can set that in the XML using the `app:layout_anchor` attribute.

**P.S.:** As stated on the docs, to change the BottomAppBar background use the `app:backgroundTint` attribute instead of the default `android:background`.

Comment: P.P.S. Even though the answer is for Android, I thought I'd leave the Flutter version as a fun fact: https://twitter.com/flutterio/status/1007677094069981184